# await Task inside awaited Task - when does the rest of the code execute?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Consider this part of Load event for main form:

```
 private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var ServerConfigFile = new ClientConfigFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        ServerConfigFile.GenerateConfigFile();
        var taskCheck = Task.Run(() => CheckUpdate());
        await taskCheck;
        lblUpdateMessage.Text = "Finished...";
        //more code here
}
```

And the `CheckUpdate` function itself:

```
 private async void CheckUpdate()
 {
        var connection = new ServerConnection(this);

        Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(lblFileDownload, () => lblFileDownload.Text = "Downloading");

        Helper.CrossThreadInvoke(lblFileDownload, () => lblFileDownload.Text = "Done");
        var taskConfig = Task.Run(() => connection.GetServerConfig());
        await taskConfig;
        ///some unrelated control changes here
}
```

Does this code waits properly for `CheckUpdate` to finish running all of its code (including the commented control changes at the end)? My reasoning is that it starts a `Task` with `CheckUpdate` in it, and `awaits`, returning control to the `MainForm`. `CheckUpdate` runs a `Task` with `GetServerConfig` function in it, `awaits`, passes control back to `MainForm_Load`, but since it's stil waiting for `CheckUpdate` to finish, it does not proceed to `lblUpdateMessage.Text = "Finished...";` line. Or am I getting it wrong?

**Tl;dr** Does this code actaully waits for all of `CheckUpdate` to finish before displaying `Finished`?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just try it and see?

Comment: I'm trying and it fails - trying to understand why it doesn't work. Is there a reason you commented without any actual advice on how to deal with it or how to improve the post?

Comment: Why are you running a method in a background thread only to have it schedule work to run in the UI thread or in another background thread?  Just run it on the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy the UI thread needs to be fully repsonsive during all of this.

Comment: @Janushoff Yes, it does.  That method isn't doing any long running non-UI work through, it's just doing UI work and scheduling non-UI work to run in another thread.

Comment: @Servy so should I just run `GetServerConfig` synchronously?

Comment: No, assuming it's actually a long running non-UI operation, which appears to be the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135885/discussion-between-janushoff-and-servy).

Comment: Perhaps my comment was a bit too subtle. Your question was essentially, "Does this code do what I think it will do?" That's not a good question, because it betrays a lack of research (namely, running the code to see what happens). Instead of asking people to run your code in their heads, perhaps you could ask what your real question is, which appears to be "Why is this code not working the way I think it should?".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - yes, that's what I mean with thsi question. It fails and I can't see why, I provided the reasoning why I think it should work, hoping for someone to point out a mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: @Janushoff You code doesn't say that it fail.  It asks if it will fail.  If you know that it fails, then apparently you already know the answer to your question.

Comment: This code appears to be IO-bound, not CPU-bound, so why Task.Run in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this code actaully waits for all of CheckUpdate to finish before displaying Finished?

No, because `CheckUpdate` is an `async void` method.

You could make it `async Task`, which would properly wait for `CheckUpdate` to complete:

```
private async Task CheckUpdate()
```

However, looking at your `CheckUpdate` function, it doesn't seem to need to run on a background thread. It updates UI controls, runs something on a background thread, and then updates UI controls. It's clearly part of the UI layer, and - as Servy pointed out - there's no point in jumping to a background thread (the `Task.Run` in `MainForm_Load`) just to jump back to the UI thread (`Helper.CrossThreadInvoke`).

So, removing these unnecessary thread jumps:

```
private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var ServerConfigFile = new ClientConfigFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
  ServerConfigFile.GenerateConfigFile();
  await CheckUpdateAsync();
  lblUpdateMessage.Text = "Finished...";
}

private async Task CheckUpdateAsync()
{
  var connection = new ServerConnection(this);
  lblFileDownload.Text = "Downloading";
  lblFileDownload.Text = "Done";
  await Task.Run(() => connection.GetServerConfig());
  // some unrelated control changes here
}
```

Finally, as EJoshuaS pointed out, `ServerConnection.GetServerConfig` definitely sounds like an I/O-based operation. You could make those calls naturally asynchronous (e.g., using `HttpClient`), removing any need for `Task.Run` at all:

```
private async Task CheckUpdateAsync()
{
  var connection = new ServerConnection(this);
  lblFileDownload.Text = "Downloading";
  lblFileDownload.Text = "Done";
  await connection.GetServerConfigAsync();
  // some unrelated control changes here
}
```